# Convert text formatted date DD.MM.YYY HH.MM to standart DD.MM.YYYY date format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, data-conversion

I have a very troublesome date format that I need to convert to standart short date as DD.MM.YYYY. I have tried some formulas as below but I cannot reach the true output. Any help will be appreciated...

[image: formulas & outputs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))
```

Then format it as `DD.MM.YYYY`

[image]